# Dataframe panda: add column based on count of group element

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe like that where column C is just 0 and 1

```
| A | B | C

| 1 | 1 | 1
| 1 | 2 | 0 
| 1 | 2 | 0 
| 1 | 2 | 1 
| 1 | 2 | 1
| 2 | 1 | 0
| 2 | 1 | 0
| 2 | 1 | 0
| 2 | 1 | 1
| 2 | 2 | 1
| 3 | 2 | 1
| 3 | 2 | 1
```

and i want to obtain a dataframe like the following.

```
| A | B | count0 | count1 

| 1 | 1 |    0   |   1
| 1 | 2 |    2   |   2
| 2 | 1 |    3   |   1
| 2 | 2 |    0   |   1
| 3 | 2 |    0   |   2
```

I basically want to add two columns (count0, count1) such that respectively counts the numbers of 0 and 1 in column C for each group of row with the same (A,B)

I've done that

```
df['count'] = df.groupby( ['A', 'B', 'C'], sort='False')['A'].transform('size')
```

obtaining this which is almost what i want but i need to split the count column based on C value

```
| A | B | C |count  

| 1 | 1 | 1 |  1  
| 1 | 2 | 0 |  2
| 1 | 2 | 1 |  2  
| 2 | 1 | 0 |  3
| 2 | 1 | 1 |  1
| 2 | 2 | 1 |  1
| 3 | 2 | 1 |  2
```

Is there a better way for doing that task, or i just do in this way?
Considering that i have millions of row (<10M)

Answer (score 0):

You want a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
out = (pd.crosstab([df['A'], df['B']], df['C'])
         .add_prefix('count')
         .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
      )
```

Output:

```
   A  B  count0  count1
0  1  1       0       1
1  1  2       2       2
2  2  1       3       1
3  2  2       0       1
4  3  2       0       2
```